# How to enable or disable an event hander in MFC?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, dialog, event-handling

I have searched the web a lot but couldn't find exactly what I want!
suppose that I have a class derived from `CWnd`. In fact, it is the class [COpenGLControl here in codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c10975/Setting-Up-OpenGL-in-an-MFC-Control.htm) customized by me for my own purposes.
the event handler for the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` button is written as follows:

```
void COpenGLControl::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    int diffX = (int)(point.x - m_fLastX);
    int diffY = (int)(point.y - m_fLastY);
    m_fLastX = (float)point.x;
    m_fLastY = (float)point.y;

    // Left mouse button
    if (nFlags & MK_LBUTTON)
    {
         m_fRotX += (float)0.5f * diffY;

         if ((m_fRotX > 360.0f) || (m_fRotX < -360.0f))
         {
             m_fRotX = 0.0f;
         }

         m_fRotY += (float)0.5f * diffX;

         if ((m_fRotY > 360.0f) || (m_fRotY < -360.0f))
         {
         m_fRotY = 0.0f;
         }
    }

    // Right mouse button
    else if (nFlags & MK_RBUTTON)
    {
        m_fZoom -= (float)0.1f * diffY;
    }

    // Middle mouse button
    else if (nFlags & MK_MBUTTON)
    {
    m_fPosX += (float)0.05f * diffX;
    m_fPosY -= (float)0.05f * diffY;
    }

    OnDraw(NULL);

    CWnd::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```

But I don't want this event handler to be `active` or `enabled` at all times. I want to put three buttons on my dialog named `pan`,`rotate` and `zoom`.
when I click `pan` I want `OnMouseMove` get active just for middle button
when I click `rotate` I want middle button get inactive and left button get active
when I click `zoom` I want left button get inactive and right one get active and so.
and finally when I click another button like `Zoom extent`, `select` and etc, I want the `OnMouseMove` event handler get inactive in such a way that even if I'm on the opengl window the `Maya-style mouse` won't be active?
How can I implement something like this whether in `my customized COpenGLControl class` or in `My MFC dialog`?
Please give some instructions to me to begin my search to find out more.

---

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ **Edited part of my question**
I also thought about adding an event-handler manually to my class just like the `OnDraw` function in the [COpenGLControl class](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c10975/Setting-Up-OpenGL-in-an-MFC-Control.htm) so did something like this:

**OpenGLContro.h**

```
afx_msg void Pan(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
```

**OpenGLControl.cpp**

```
void COpenGLControl::Pan(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)  
{
    int diffX = (int)(point.x - m_fLastX);
    int diffY = (int)(point.y - m_fLastY);
    if (nFlags & MK_MBUTTON)
    {
        m_fPosX += (float)0.05f * diffX;
        m_fPosY -= (float)0.05f * diffY;
    }
    OnDraw(NULL);
}
```

and whenever the button `pan` is clicked I will call this function but there I'm not still on the `OpenGL Window` and don't know hat to pass as the parameters to the function `Pan`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a state/mode member variable to the class and for each "mode" a dedicated handler function. The event handlers you use the mode variable to decide, which of the mode dependent handlers you call from the event handler, passing all the parameters.

Comment: I mean the handler with the code above is always active(whenever you are on the opengl window) Can I make it inactive sometimes?

Comment: I also thought about adding an event handler manually to the class. Please see the edited part of my question if you're interested.