# How to implement a WM_LBUTTONCLICK event handler

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, event-handling, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

Suppose that I have [the COpenGLControl class derived from CWnd](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c10975/Setting-Up-OpenGL-in-an-MFC-Control.htm) and I'm customizing it for my own purposes.
I want to do something like this:
**1- Add a zoom tool toolbar button at top of my dialog.

2- after pressing the toolbar button mentioned the feature explained below gets enabled.

3- If the user clicks the left mouse button we get zoomed in by a factor of two and glTranslate to the position of the user's click.

4-If the user clicks the right mouse button we get zoomed out by a factor of 0.5 and glTranslate to the position of the user's click.

5-If the user clicks another toolbar button the feature explained in two above steps gets disabled.**

You know I want to implement something like `Zoom Tool` in `Global Mapper`.

I don't have problems with implementing `glScale` or `glTranslate`.
Just have problems with the MFC part.
searching the default message handlers, I found that we have `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`,`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`,`WM_LBUTTONUP`,`WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK`,`WM_RBUTTONDOWN`,`WM_RBUTTONUP` but not a `WM_LBUTTONCLK` or `WM_RBUTTONCLK`?

even if we had `WM_LBUTTONCLK` or `WM_RBUTTONCLK`, these event handlers would be enabled and active since creation of the window until closing it but I want them to be active just at a certain time (after clicking zoom tool and before clicking another tool)
I know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18430091/1245120) that maybe I need to implement these features in user-defined message handlers but I don't have any idea since I'm new to MFC.
Could you help me give the true idea to start from?

Comment: In the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18430091/1245120) you provide there is no mention of "user defined" message handlers. Just implement a [ON_LBUTTONDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa232230(v=vs.60).aspx) handler and decide in the handler what you want to do according to the state of your software.

Comment: ok @Michael Walz after posting the question, I implemented the ON_LBUTTONDOWN handler. It works just as I expect. but the problem is this handler is always active and whenever I go on the opengl window and left-click the glScale and glTranslate is runned. But I told, I want the handler to be active at a certain time(after clicking `zoom tool` toolbar button at top of my dialog and before clicking other toolbar buttons). In fact, I asked how can I make mouse-event handlers to be active at certain times? I don't know!

Comment: or how can I make mouse WM_LBUTTONDOWN message be sent just at certain times?

Comment: I don't know if there's a need to implement user-defined message handlers and then send the corresponding messages in certain parts of my program?

Comment: please help me giving any suitable idea **How to make default MFC CWnd event-handlers be active at certain times or how to implement user-defined event-handlers that catch corresponding messages at certain times?**

Comment: I don't really get it. What's the problem if your handler gets called and you just do nothing in it. It's the same as if there was no handler at all isn't it ?

Comment: suppose that for example the user is not intended to zoom but the cursor is in the window and by mistake the user does a click. But when the user has clicked the `zoom tool at top of the dialog` it means that he is intended to do zooming. besides this way you can use an event handler for more than one task. If you are familiar with a portable software like `Global Mapper`, consider the `zoom` and `pan` tools in it?

Comment: Look at the answer below.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36262/discussion-between-michael-walz-and-sepideh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something similar to this:

```
void COpenGLControl::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    if (zoom_tool_has_been_clicked)
    {
        // do zoom stuff here

        return ;
    }

    CWnd::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

Just to give you an idea.

Comment: oh you're right. in fact [it is like datenwolf's suggestion to define a mode for my class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429947/how-to-enable-or-disable-an-event-hander-in-mfc/18430091#18430091) but I don't know why I didn't understand his purpose. It seems that I'm always searching for difficult solutions. I'm so stupid.

Comment: but @Michael Walz could you explain in your answer alittle about **where is it better to use user-defined messages?**, **In what cases or situations are they used?** just alittle to get familiar with the situations that they are used?  If I get familiar with these situations, I will do more search about user-defined messages in case of encountering such a situation. thanks for your attention!

Comment: User defined messages are only useful if you want to send something else that one of the standard WM_* messages. In your case you want to handle the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message so there is no need to use a user defined message.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a nonstandard event that may need to be handled?  thanks @Michael Walz

Comment: This answer is wrong.  It's better to "fire" the click event on mouse up, not mouse down.  Capture the mouse when you get a click down and either do your zoom or not on mouse up.  If you don't capture the mouse, you can ignore the up if the mouse cursor is outside of the area of your control.  This allows a user to "cancel" the click by moving the mouse outside of the region if he's previously pressed down inside of it.